# Server-side asp Moss 2007

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-config, moss

I need help enabling server-side scripting, I've referred to tutorials but the changes do not appear to be taking affect.

An error occurred during the processing of /CMD/Pages/gjgc.aspx. Code blocks are not allowed in this file.

I know the solution is to edit the web.config an add a line for the PageParser. Problem is when I make the change I still get the error.

The page is located at http//xxx/CMD/Pages/route.aspx (Port 80)

This is the entry I'm adding into the web.config:

```
<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="false" DirectFileDependencies="10" TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="false"> 

  <PageParserPaths> 
  <PageParserPath VirtualPath="~/CMD/Pages/route.aspx" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true"/> 
  </PageParserPaths>
```

I can't figure out why the changes are not taking affect or is my use of the Virtual path incorrect?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll probably have more luck if you post in the dedicated SharePoint site at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

To enable code blocks on a Folder, do a wildcard like such:

```
<PageParserPath VirtualPath="/CMD/Pages/*" 
    CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true"  
        IncludeSubFolders="true"/>
```

Otherwise, to enable code blocks on a File:

```
<PageParserPath VirtualPath="/CMD/Pages/Test.aspx" 
    CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" />
```

Note the 2 changes: VirtualPath and IncludeSubFolders

Please iisreset after each web.config change.